# Django Celery Heroku - Changed Redis URL enviro variable, now getting error

Tags: django, heroku, redis, celery

I updated the enviro variable, known as config vars in Heroku for REDDIS_URL

I turned off both my app dyno and my worker dyno.

I then restarted my app dyno, `web gunicorn myapplication.wsgi` and have no issues

I then restarted my worker `worker celery -A myapplication worker -l info --concurrency 2` Which causes me to get the following error in logs `[2021-07-06 16:00:05: ERROR/MainProcess] Cannot connect to redis://NEW_REDDIS_URL//: Error while reading from socket: (104, 'Connection reset by peer').`

How do I get the worker to reference the updated config var (enviro variable) for REDDIS_URL?

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to set your redis URL in settings.py with OS `os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')`

Heroku rotates credentials periodically and updates applications where this datastore is attached.

Heroku recommends using encryption and thus a `rediss://` URL instead of `redis://`

For celery, something like: CELERY_BROKER_URL = `'rediss://:{Password}@{Host}:{Port}'`

Heroku command to get this url easy `heroku redis:credentials REDIS_URL`

Referer: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#using-the-cli